# jquery signin and refresh

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have a main page in jquery-mobile which contains following code

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']))
{
    if($_SESSION['signed_in']==true)
    {    
        echo '<a href="signout.php" data-role="button">Signout </a>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="signin.php" data-role="button">Signin </a>';
}
?>
```

The user is signed in or not is checked on server(obviously!)

But the problem is that **after signing in, when the user goes to home page, "Signin" option
is shown. It is only when user refreshes page manually that "Signout" option is shown**.

So how do I solve this error? How can I make jquery load page from server always and not store it in some cache or anything.

Comment: I think the problem is cache..

Comment: I tried using data-prefetch="false" but that disables the animation.

Comment: i have no idea about that...you can use something like `window.reload=true` or a load event

Answer (score 2):

Make jQuery add the sign in or sign out button, in condition that the request was successful.
 
Use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to insert html to the page. It will make the page look if it was refreshed.